# Secure, scheduled transfer from windows to centos

Tags: ssh, centos, sftp, rsync, scp

What is the most secure way to transfer files from a Windows server (or machine) to a remote web server running CentOS?  I have been using wget as a cron job to access an FTP site and transfer the files, but I am concerned about the security of transferring files via FTP.

I like the idea of using key pairs from the servers, but I'm not sure how to do this or how to create the SSH script.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get `pscp.exe` from http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html. To make a ppk key for pscp from a linux key you need to get PuttyGen and go to `Conversions/Import Key`. After that you need a command like the following:

```
C:\path\to\pscp.exe -i key.ppk C:\path\to\file.txt user@host:/directory
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this.  I'd like for my remote dedicated web server (which is running CentOS/WHM/cPanel) to retrieve files from a Windows machine/network.  I would like to automate the task on the remote webserver.  I'm not sure how to set up the server on the Windows side.  I'd like to put the matching key on the webserver so it can log into the windows machine via SFTP without a password, automatically.  This will allow me to schedule the cron job and securely transfer the files.  Are your instructions advising how to set this up?  Seems like vice versa.  Let me know please.

Comment: Yes, I understood the reverse.

Comment: Check out this article on setting it up: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/itdojo/set-up-a-free-ssh-server-on-windows-7-with-freesshd/3506